# How do I get the count/size of an array in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, mvel

I want to do a statistical facet on one of my arrays. I hope something like

```
"script" : "doc['myField'].doubleValue
```

or

```
"script" : "doc['myField'].count
```

would work. I havent found any array count method in mvel and I don't even know if accessing the array field in a script actually gives me the array.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733351/how-do-i-sort-the-search-results-according-to-the-number-of-items-in-elasticsear/12734613#12734613

Answer (score 5):

I might have it. It seems I need to count a field inside the array instead of the array itself. This might just be because all I have are arrays of objects.

```
"script" : "doc['arrayField.objectField'].values.length"
```

Comment: Ha, I did this and it totally killed my cluster. Maybe there is a way to do this with better performance.

Comment: It killed your cluster because it loaded all values of this field into memory and before version 0.90 elasticsearch was using quite  inefficient structure to keep values for multi-valued fields in memory. So, you have a few options here: upgrade to 0.90.0.Beta1, use _fields instead of doc if this field is stored or to index the length of the array as another field. The last solution is the best in my opinion.